# Data with same name has been uploaded from another PS4?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I just turned on my PS4, and received a notification to tell me a saved game could not be automatically uploaded.

Looking at some more detailed information I was told that "Data with same name has been uploaded from another PS4".

Considering I only own 1 PS4 and you can't even activate more than 1 PS4 at the same time, I was wondering what exactly happened.

Could this particular error message have been triggered by the fact that I manually uploaded my savegame to the cloud before putting my PS4 to sleep? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I get this error message fairly regularly, and have only manually uploaded from the notification menu after it has already failed.

Comment: I think this is a bug introduced in the 1.7 update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://gearnuke.com/ps4-1-70-firmware-update-causing-issues-save-data-uploading-save-data-cloud/) article, this has been happening increasingly ever since the 1.7 update which introduced several features. It's important to notice that this ***HAS*** happened before to other users but it wasn't as often or to as many people as now.

It's important to notice that I *did not* find any *official statement from Sony* regarding this.